# Problem appending options to a select from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have this Json from a $.getJson function:

```
[
    {"UserName":"Z1","FullName":"XY1"},
    {"UserName":"Z2","FullName":"XY2"},
    {"UserName":"Z3","FullName":"XY3"}
]
```

I try to append these into options of a select tag as a pair of value end text. I've tried this:

```
$.each(data, function(i,item) {
  alert(item.UserName + " " + item.FullName);
});
```

but it gave me: `undefined undefined`.

I think it should work. What's wrong?

Comment: can we see your `$.getJSON` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ZKBYU/

Comment: Yes, and I have another getJson call in the same js file and it works perfectly. I don't know where the problem is. Thanx the answer.

Comment: I have found the solution at last. I made a mistake. I used twice Json() call to create Json string. Thank you.